# Pitch accent websites differing for certain words

Tags: pitch-accent, resources

For the word 九日 (ここのか{LHHH}), both [OJAD](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/eng/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:invisible/limit:20/word:%E4%B9%9D%E6%97%A5) and [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B9%9D%E6%97%A5) agree on the pitch accent of the word itself, but for the particle that comes afterwords (say 九日の), they differ by this:

> OJAD: ここのかの{LHHHH}
>   weblio: ここのかの{LHHHL}

From what I can see both sources seem fairly reliable, so does this mean that both pitches are considered standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes a word does have multiple "valid" pitch accent patterns.  Daijirin often lists multiple pitch downstep numbers for terms that have them, like, say, [the entry for とらまえる](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%8D%95%E3%81%BE%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B), which lists patterns 4 and 3.  That said, [the Daijirin entry for ここのか](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B) only lists pitch pattern 4, with a downstep after the fourth mora.

Checking in my local copy of the NHK アクセント辞典, they list two patterns -- 4 for the noun, and 0 (no downstep) for the adverb.  However, a bit confusingly, both entries (noun and adverb) include the same sample sentence:

> あと​ココノカデ{LHHHL}期限が来る *(noun)*
>
> あと​ココノカデ{LHHHH}期限が来る *(adverb)*

It seems that Daijirin wound up using one pattern, and OJAD the other, but if the NHK is anything to go by, it looks like both patterns 4 and 0 are recognized as correct.

Comment: The 2016 version of NHK lists them as 4 for the noun and 0 for the adverb and the examples correctly reflect that `ココノカニ{LHHHL}退院した`, `ココノカ{LHHH}たった`.

Comment: @keji -- I have electronic version 1.02, but frustratingly, I cannot find when this version was published.  Good to know that they added better examples in the 2016 version.

Answer (score 4):

I personally read 九日から like ここのかから【LHHHHH】, but ここのかから【LHHHLL】 is also acceptable. 九日の天気 is read both like ここのかのてんき【LHHHHHLL】 and ここのかのてんき【LHHHLHLL】, but I feel the former is more common.

Some words are pronunced in two ways depending on the speaker. See: [ズボン pronunciation variation & explanation for](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58646/5010) and [Are there any rules to the intonations they are discussing in this video?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74609/5010)

FWIW, [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=ja&client=tw-ob#ja/en/%E4%B9%9D%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A9%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AF%E9%9B%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%80%82%E4%B9%9D%E6%97%A5%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%99%B4%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%80%82) agrees with me.